# How to query the database using ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model

I've confirmed through the rails console that this record doesn't exist.  However, when I run this code, 'it exists' gets printed to the console.

Is there an issue with how I'm querying the database using ruby?

```
        if Companyavg.where(:company => 'goog', :word => 'baa')
            puts 'it exists'
        else
            puts 'doesnt exist'
        end
```

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
if Companyavg.where(:company => 'goog', :word => 'baa')
```

to:

```
if Companyavg.where(:company => 'goog', :word => 'baa').exists?
```

This is more efficient than using `present?` since it can run an optimized query to return the correct result.

The initial query that you had will always be truthy since it returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` (in simple terms, a lazy untriggered query).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Companyavg.where(:company => 'goog', :word => 'baa).empty?
```

The issue is that the `where` call is returning a query, but it doesn't actually run the query until it absolutely has to.  So in this case you're evaluating the truth value of a non-nil, non-false object, which is therefore `true` according to the rules of Ruby.

Comment: Looks like @PinnyM's solution is probably slightly more efficient, according to [this link](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3179).

Answer (score 0):

This is because where returns an empty relation. In ruby only nil and false statements evaluate as false. For example 0 and "" (empty string) evaluate as true.

Comment: This isn't accurate - it returns an untriggered relation that doesn't know yet if it's empty or not.

Comment: Ruby does regular evaluations; ActiveRecord queries do lazy evaluations.